# never extends any is true or false in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
type t<U> = U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never

// true
type t1 = never extends any ? true : false

// never
type t2 = t<never>
```

I'm confused and I'm wondering why

Comment: This is typescript, not javascript. Please tag...

Comment: note: `type t<U> = U extends any ? (k: U) => void : Foo` still makes `t2` `never`